# Asp.net MVC Routing - Preventing a route to an XML file with a constraint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to find a way to preventing a user from accessing a specific xml file.  I've tried doing...

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "SiteMap",
     "SiteMap/siteMap.xml",
     new { },
     new { isLocal = new LocalHostRouteConstraint() });
```

Where the LocalHostRouteConstraint() is...

```
public class LocalHostRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return !httpContext.Request.IsLocal;
    }
}
```

This is the implementation on this page...

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs

But routes are still allowed to access the xml!

Is there another way to prevent this?

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention to ignore the ! In the LocalHostRouteConstrsint class.  Was doing that for testing for it to work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why don't you just use routes.IgnoreRoute("SiteMap/siteMap.xml") ?

Comment: you could also try `routes.IgnoreRoute("{*sitemap}", new { sitemap = @"(.*/)?siteMap.xml(/.*)?" });`

Comment: @frennky I've tried that, but a user could still directly type the path into the address bar and get the .xml file.  I'm looking for a way to prevent the user to navigate to that file.

Comment: @Aivan ill try that in the morning and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the restriction have to be in the MVC routes?

If not, you can put the following right before the `</configuration>` closing tag in your `web.config`:

```
<location path="SiteMap/siteMap.xml">
     <system.web>
        <authorization>
           <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
     </system.web>
 </location>
```

Comment: It does not have to be.  I'll give this a shot as well.